# CR versus LF: which should I recognize as "end of line" in terminal program?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, terminal

I understand the use of line feed and/or carriage return as line separators in Windows, Macintosh and Linux. But now I'm writing a program that will accept text user input over a TCP socket, and I need to know what I should recognize as an "end of line" marker when parsing typed text.

I've only seen a line feed sent when a user types RETURN on a connected terminal. Will carriage returns ever be sent? If so, will they always be part of a CRLF pair, or might a certain terminal program send a lone CR to indicate "the user just pressed RETURN"?

Comment: This is in no way opinion based. I need to write a program that accepts TCP connections from a variety of connecting terminal programs, and want to know what character(s) I'll need to interpret as "the user just pressed RETURN". Below you'll find an answer that cites references on what characters need to be understood as a press of the RETURN key. How is that based on opinion?

Comment: You can alway keep all and choose the proper one case by case. When you estabilish the connection you can _ask_ from which system the client is  writing from...

Comment: No, because I am not going to support the Telnet protocol, just bare TCP sockets. Most of the time the client will actually be someone's program; I just want to be able to handle someone using telnet, or putty, or whatever.

Comment: Since here this question is closed, If you mind, you can reformulate this question on Stack Overflow for a programmers' optic answer and a broader audience or, maybe even better, on Unix & Linux. Just add some details or specification to help the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I was you, I’d use the same standards as other common Internet protocols which use TCP. I’m most familiar with HTTP and SMTP, both of which use a  carriage-return / line-feed  pair:

#### HTTP

According to the RFC for [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence `CR LF` as the end-of-line marker for all protocol elements except the entity-body

#### SMTP

In the [original RFC for Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) a `line` is defined as

> a sequence of ASCII characters ending with a `<CRLF>`.

#### Newline

The [Newline Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) also
has the this to say:

> Most textual Internet protocols (including HTTP, SMTP, FTP, IRC and many others) mandate the use of ASCII CR+LF ('\r\n', 0x0D 0x0A) on the protocol level, but recommend that tolerant applications recognize lone LF ('\n', 0x0A) as well.